# Inserir um submenu dentro de um JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

Quando clico no ícone da mulher ou do homem na `JFrame`, é chamado uma `JPanel` onde insiro os dados como peso e a altura. Mas ao clicar em salvar, não posso chamar outro `JPanel` para mostrar o resultado do cálculo, pois já estou em uma.

Há alguma forma de colocar um item de menu dentro do ícone da mulher ou do homem, como se fosse um sub-atalho?

Classe principal JFrame:

```
public class Home extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Home() {
    initComponents();
    }

    private void jImcHomemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        ImcHomem imcHomem = new ImcHomem();
        this.setContentPane(imcHomem);
        this.pack();
    } 
// ...
}
```

Classe onde o usuário informa os dados(peso e altura) JPanel

```
public class ImcHomem extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    double pesoH;
    double alturaH;

    private void jBtnSalvarHActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                            
    // variável pesoH recebe o valor passado para Double do botão jTextPesoH
    pesoH = Double.parseDouble(jTextPesoH.getText());
    // variável alturaH recebe o valor passado para Double do botão jTextAlturaH
    alturaH = Double.parseDouble(jTextAlturaH.getText());
    // inseri os dados no botão Salvar só para ter certeza de que o código está correto
    jBtnSalvarH.setText("Peso: "+pesoH+" kg "+" e altura: "+alturaH+" cm");
    ResultHomem resuH = new ResultHomem();
    }                                           

    private void jTextPesoHActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        pesoH = Double.parseDouble(jTextPesoH.getText());
    }                                          

    private void jTextAlturaHActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt{                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        alturaH = Double.parseDouble(jTextAlturaH.getText());
    }
// ...
}
```

Classe que chamaria pra mostrar o resultado

```
public class ResultHomem extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
    * Creates new form ResultHomem
    */
    public ResultHomem() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void jTextResultHActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }
    // ...
}
```

[image: JFrame (Tela inicial) - Local onde seleciono o ícone para fazer o calculo do IMC]

Comment: Ester, eu ja havia respondido, você tentou a solução abaixo? É basicamente isso a resposta;

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um `JMenu` normalmente e adicioná-lo ao menu principal, não tem segredo ;)

```
menu = new JMenu("Calcular Imc");

subMenu01 = new JMenu("homem");
mSubItem01 =  new JMenuItem("calcular");
subMenu01.add(mSubItem01 );

subMenu02 = new JMenu("mulher");
msubItem02 = new JMenuItem("calcular");
subMenu02.add(msubItem02);

menu.add(subMenu01);
menu.add(subMenu02);
menubar.add(menu);
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Referência:**

[Adding a submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30000464/5524514)

Comment: Bom, bem simples e fácil de entender :) +1